# Disabling Azure auto-instrumentation (app insights) in nodejs api app

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to disable codeless monitoring for an Azure api app we have deployed.  We want to track all request manually using the trackNodeHttpRequest method because the app insight transaction log is filled with requests ever 30 seconds from the app gateway health checks.

When I set setAutoCollectRequests(false) it doesn't seem to stop the auto monitoring / codeless sdk.  What am I missing here?

```
const appInsights = require("applicationinsights");

appInsights.setup()
  .setAutoCollectRequests(false)
  .setAutoCollectConsole(true, true)
  .start();

app.use((req, res, next) => {
   if (!req.url.toLowerCase().startsWith('/swagger')) {
       appInsights.defaultClient.trackNodeHttpRequest({request:req, response:res});
   }
   next();
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue by disabling the app insights configuration in the api app settings.  This is where the documentation is a little confusing https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/azure-web-apps-nodejs?tabs=windows

> If both auto-instrumentation monitoring and manual SDK-based
> instrumentation are detected, only the manual instrumentation settings
> will be honored. This is to prevent duplicate data from being sent. To
> learn more about this, check out the troubleshooting section below.

I did not find this the case with app insights turned on and setAutoCollectRequests(false) in my code it was ignoring my manual tracking code above.  Disabling the setting still allows me to see my manual tracking in the app insights.

[image]